# Can anyone recommend a REST / SOAP Web Service for eSignatures on DocuSign?

Tags: rest, soap, docusignapi

I'm getting ready to integrate **eSignatures** to an app I'm building an I've chosen DocuSign to accomplish this. I see that they have a REST api and a SOAP api, any recommendations or pros/cons to choosing one over the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DocuSign actually has a little blurb about this on their Developer Center- what they say is that both protocols (REST & SOAP) are actively supported and both are robust, however they encourage REST over SOAP since it's the newer protocol and because the feature gap between REST and SOAP is growing.

This is the text from their website I'm referring to:

"If you are more comfortable using the SOAP protocol instead of REST then feel free to do so! The SOAP API is robust and fully supported, but please note that it's possible features added in the future might be added to the REST API and not SOAP. We're still adding features to SOAP and have no plans of retiring it anytime soon, but we can't guarantee features that are added to REST moving forward will also be added to SOAP."

[DocuSign Developer Center](http://www.docusign.com/developer-center)